# Adding CameraOverlayView to UIImagePicker

Tags: xamarin, camera, xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

I am stuck in creating a CameraOverlayView on the UIImagePicker my Xamarin.iOS application 
here is my code to launch the cameraView

```
{
var imagePickerControl = new UIImagePickerController();
imagePickerControl.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
imagePickerControl.ShowsCameraControls = false;
//imagePickerControl.CameraOverlayView = new CameraOverlayView();
var imagePickerDelegate = new CameraImagePicker(this);
imagePickerControl.Delegate = imagePickerDelegate;
NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(imagePickerControl, true);
}
```

the above code helped me creating a imagepicker with no controls...
can somebody help me creating a CameraOverlayview :UIView 
I m trying to create a custom UI and basic controls (with 2 imagebuttons and UI like its in instagram Camera screen)

Comment: Why have you commented out `imagePickerControl.CameraOverlayView `?  First initialize your custom view, then assign it to CameraOverlayView before presenting imagepicker

Comment: Actually I m unaware how to implement the CameraOverlayView() class which i have not created yet due to lack of working examples.  Can You help me with the structure of  CameraOverlayView:UIView  class

Comment: Look at the sample code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590346/using-cameraoverlayview-with-uiimagepickercontroller) in the Question

Comment: I have gone through almost every ios example on forums etc , but cant find a perfect way with xamarin code to get cameraoverlayview on my cameraview....
thanks in advance

Comment: [Adding CameraOverlayView on XaamiOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56183433/8732045)